# Kubernetes preStop hook does not sleep

Tags: kubernetes, graceful-shutdown

I am trying to add preStop hook to my k8s container but for some reason sleep seems like it does not work. I tried to add echo and in that case I can see that it work. But when I replace echo with sleep it seems like it does not work and sleep because pod is removed before given number of seconds in the sleep command.

```
lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            command:
              - sleep 60
```

Note than my gracefulTerminationPeriod is above 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see doc
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

command and args much write in array format, you cannot just use space

```yaml
lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            command:
              - sleep
              - 60
```

Comment: The format I posted above is auto format after I enter as command: [sleep 60]. When I manually edit as you mentioned above it complains.

Comment: it is array, you need comma in between `command: ['sleep', '60']`

Comment: thanks a lot you are right I was aware missing comma. Is it possible to send http request outside of the pod during that time ? I am receiving refuse during that period.